# Visual Studio Code Node.js Create Module

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, node-modules

I am new to Node.js development ,I know how to create a module through command line, but because I have chosen Visual Studio Code as IDE to develop my project i want to know how I create a module through Visual Studio Code. Should I have to create the internal command line in Visual Studio Code ?

Thanks in advance.
Best regards.

Comment: What do you mean? To initialize a Node.js project?

Comment: create a module inside Visual Studio Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your terminal you create a folder for your module, run "npm init" in it and you open that folder in VSCode.

VSCode is just a text editor, not an IDE, even tho it has so much plugins and features, it feels like an IDE.